# Apostrophe is escaped in JSON array of strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have the following in a .json file:

```
{
    "WRATH OF THE C’TAN": {
        "description": "The C’tan’s ever-burning rage at their enslavement is turned upon the enemy with cataclysmic results.",
        "stratagem": "Use this Stratagem after a C’TAN SHARD from your army has resolved a Power of the C’tan. Roll a D6 to randomly select a Power of the C’tan from page 113. The C’tan Shard immediately uses the power rolled, even if it has already used that power this phase.",
        "cost": 2,
        "conditions": [
            "factionkeywords"
        ],
        "factionkeywords": [
            "C'tan Shards"
        ]
    }
}
```

I am reading in the JSON file with the following code and running it with Node:

```
var fileContents = fs.readFileSync(path, "utf8").toString();
library = JSON.parse(fileContents);
```

I am iterating the factionkeywords array read in from the JSON file and comparing each string (in this case one, some others have more) to a unit to see if its factionkeywords contains that string.

The issue I'm running into is the string in the factionkeywords array is escaping the apostrophe. When I console.log the object, I get this:

```
{
    description: 'The powers of the C’tan are myriad and terrifying. To battle a fragment of these shackled star gods is to find reality unbound.',
    stratagem: 'Use this Stratagem at the start of your Movement phase. Select a C’TAN SHARD from your army. That model can replace one of its Powers of the C’tan with a different Power of the C’tan of your choice.',
    cost: 1,
    conditions: [ 'factionkeywords' ],
    factionkeywords: [ 'C\'tan Shards' ]
}
```

I do not understand why the apostrophe is escaped in the array string, but not in the description or stratagem strings. As a result, I am unable to check if a unit contains this string since it will not match.

I've done quite a few google searches, but haven't been able to find anything. Everything that comes up is how to add escapes. I want to know why it is automatically escaping the apostrophes on import, but only in the array and not the other strings.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: focus on the Single quotation mark. They both are different. In factionkeywords, it's not apostrophe, but single quotation mark, used as apostrophe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The escape is added by `console.log` in order to not confuse the apostrophe with the start and end single quotes, for which it uses the same character. It does not exist in your string. Try `console.log(myobject.factionkeywords[0])` to see your string as it truly is.

The reason no escaping was done on `description` is because you don't have the same character there. `factionkeywords` contains 'APOSTROPHE' (U+0027), while `description` contains 'RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK' (U+2019).

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem. I'll remember to keep an eye out for different character types. Some of the information I copy/pasted, some I entered myself. Hopefully this will help some other poor soul like myself.